# printing json object by ajax code in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

i am trying to print a js .. on object by ajax in the client side (.jsp )but it tell me an error occurred .. here is my code
in servlet

```
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("json", "1213");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter(); 
    pw.print(json.toString());
    pw.close();
```

in jsp

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({

        url : "Server",
        dataType : 'json',
        error : function() {

            alert("Error Occured");
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);

        }
    });
});
```

any suggestions ??

Comment: what kind of error? You should use `error : function(that, e) {console.log(e);})` and then look in the javascript console of your browser.

Comment: here it is "the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Well obviously your path is wrong in request

Comment: i changed it tp"http://localhost:8080/startNew/Server" and then "parse error appeared

Comment: why u trying to print the json on an alert? its better to use the console.log(data)

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr. parse error appearing .. why ?

Comment: try with this: 

 alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr. the same error appear

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr. any suggestions ??

Comment: change it to `http://localhost:8080/startNew/Server`

Answer (score 0):

please try below code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({

            url : "PlaceCorrectPath",
            dataType : 'json',
            error : function() {

                alert("Error Occured");
            },
            success : function(data) {
               var val= $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(val.YourKeyName)

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please let me know the error and also make sure success function returns some JSON data in response

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S

Comment: Try to Parse JSON data as $.parseJSON(data.d)

Comment: Plaese use alert(JSON.stringify(data)) in success function and let me know what you are getting in response

Comment: the project named startNew

Comment: is the server sent the object to jsp or not ??

Comment: i think your server is  not returning the correct JSON format.

Comment: so how to do that ??

Comment: i have not much experience in JSP but if your server will return the correct JSON then my code will  definitely work.